# HTTP Basic Authentication - what's the expected web browser experience?

Tags: basic-authentication

When a server allows access via Basic HTTP Authentication, what is the experience expected to be **in a web browser**?

Ignoring the web browser for a moment, here's how to create a Basic Auth request with `curl`:

```
curl -u myusername:mypassword http://somesite.example
```

But what about in a Web Browser? What I've seen on some websites, is I visit the URL, and then the server returns response code 401. The browser then displays a username/password prompt.

However, on `somesite.example`, I'm not getting an authorization prompt at all, just a page that says I'm not authorized. Did somesite not implement the Basic Auth workflow correctly, or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Are you sure you use Basic Auth and not Digest?

Comment: not sure of the difference, unless you are asking if I base-64 encode. if i was doing that programatically it would, but curl does that for me.

Comment: You can find out what authentication is used from WWW-Authenticate response header (value: Digest or Basic).

Comment: I think this question needs to be rephrased.  More than one respondent thinks it's a question about curl rather than the browser.

Comment: Do you mean "authentication" when you use term "authorization" ?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

To help everyone avoid confusion, I will reformulate the question in two parts.

First: **"how can make an authenticated HTTP request with a browser, using BASIC auth?"**.

In the browser you can do a HTTP basic auth first by waiting the prompt to come, or by editing the URL if you follow this format: `http://myusername:mypassword@somesite.example`

NB: the curl command mentionned in the question is perfectly fine, if you have a command-line and curl installed. ;)

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#URL_encoding
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-18

Also according to the CURL manual page https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html

```
HTTP

  Curl also supports user and password in HTTP URLs, thus you can pick a file
  like:

      curl http://name:passwd@machine.domain/full/path/to/file

  or specify user and password separately like in

      curl -u name:passwd http://machine.domain/full/path/to/file

  HTTP offers many different methods of authentication and curl supports
  several: Basic, Digest, NTLM and Negotiate (SPNEGO). Without telling which
  method to use, curl defaults to Basic. You can also ask curl to pick the
  most secure ones out of the ones that the server accepts for the given URL,
  by using --anyauth.

  NOTE! According to the URL specification, HTTP URLs can not contain a user
  and password, so that style will not work when using curl via a proxy, even
  though curl allows it at other times. When using a proxy, you _must_ use
  the -u style for user and password.
```

The second and real question is **"However, on `somesite.example`, I'm not getting an authorization prompt at all, just a page that says I'm not authorized. Did somesite not implement the Basic Auth workflow correctly, or is there something else I need to do?"**

The curl documentation says the `-u` option supports many method of authentication, Basic being the default.

Comment: The question is about curl, which is not a browser.

Comment: You may have not read the question entirely, as it says just under the curl command: "However, right now I don't have access to curl (long story), and I want to just do it from the web browser, if possible." ;)

Comment: I totally agree that curl works fine, I personnally use it on a regular basis, but the question is not about curl...

Comment: The asker wants to know why auth. isn't working in the browser.  The question isn't about cURL.

Answer (score 69):

Have you tried?

```
curl somesite.example --user username:password
```

Comment: @daronwolff You only switched the arguments positions and replaced -u with --user (which is only the long term), but apart from that you wrote exactly what the OP already wrote in his question

Comment: The asker wants to know why auth. isn't working in the browser.  The question isn't about cURL.

Answer (score 15):

You might have old invalid username/password cached in your browser. Try clearing them and check again.

If you are using IE and `somesite.example` is in your Intranet security zone, IE may be sending your Windows credentials automatically.

Answer (score 9):

#### WWW-Authenticate header

You may also get this if the server is sending a 401 response code but not setting the WWW-Authenticate header correctly - I should know, I've just fixed that in out own code because VB apps weren't popping up the authentication prompt.

Answer (score 7):

If there are no credentials provided in the request headers, the following is the minimum response required for IE to prompt the user for credentials and resubmit the request.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.StatusCode = (Int32)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Postman a plugin for chrome.
It gives the ability to choose the authentication type you need for each of the requests.
In that menu you can configure user and password.
Postman will automatically translate the config to a authentication header that will be sent with your request.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% related to the OP but I couldn't find any answers to this, so my solution may help someone else.

In Firefox, on certain sites I wasn't getting the Basic Authentication popup, and I could see a 401 in the access logs. So basically the server thought I had a bad password and the browser was somehow caching this. I could figure out how to reset the password in Firefox, until I eventually realised that you can just do this to reset Firefox's cached password:

```
https://user/password@url-requiring-basic-authentication
```

Hopefully that will save someone else some pain if they find themselves in the same boat.