# How to curl login authentication like this

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, remote-login

I want to login curl with php or another language

example site : http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/mystatus.cgi

when curl site will alert authentication below picture how to sign in for retrieve data

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Basic Authentication - what's the expected browser experience?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044340/http-basic-authentication-whats-the-expected-browser-experience)

Comment: OK this issue resolve https://stackoverflow.com/a/19871279/9551013 thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

This is called HTTP Basic Authentication.

In order to authenticate use the CURLOPT_USERPWD option.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USERNAME:PASSWORD");
```

Comment: OK this issue resolve  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19871279/9551013 thank you everyone